# using grep within the sh -c command

Tags: linux, shell, grep, sh, xargs

I try to use the `grep` command within `sh -c`, but it turns out it would always miss the first argument passed from `xargs`.
How could I fix this issue a?

Here is the test I did on my laptop:

```
[beta@fat01 slab-spacingTest]$ ls out*
out-0.06  out-0.08  out-0.1
[beta@fat01 slab-spacingTest]$ ls out* | xargs echo
out-0.06 out-0.08 out-0.1

[beta@fat01 slab-spacingTest]$ ls out* | xargs sh -c 'for i do echo "$i";grep etot "$i" | tail -n 1; done'
out-0.08
 etot  = -6.35545639E+04 abs_ev   =  7.24E-04 rel_ev   =  5.81E-08
out-0.1
 etot  = -6.35550650E+04 abs_ev   =  5.53E-05 rel_ev   =  4.43E-09
```

Comment: No need of `ls | xargs` just use: `for i in out*; do echo "$i";grep -F 'etot' "$i" | tail -n 1; done`

Comment: You should do what @anubhava suggested. But to answer the question, (which is probably a duplicate), the first argument of `sh -c ...` is used as `$0`, so add an argument `_` after the command string, like: `sh -c 'echo "$#:" "$@"' _ a b`